# Replacing the power steering hose(s)

Tags: power-steering, replace, leak

On my 92 Ford Explorer I have a terrible power steering fluid leak.

If someone turns the whee all the way left or right RIGHT before it hits the turn lock, fluid starts squirting out of one of the hoses like a pressure washer.

I know I need a normal wrench to remove the top portion of the hose connected to the pump, but what about the other end? It looks difficult to remove.

Comment: Does the HP line go directly from your pump to your steering rack or does it go to a cooler, or if not, how is it attached? Seems to me looking at pictures of the line, it should be a straight forward removal.

Comment: Goes straight to the steering rack along with the return line right next to it.

However, it doesn't seem straight forward at all.. what tool would even be capable of loosening that nut?

For the return: I can easily grasp and slide down the clamp with pliers on the pump-connected side. For the other side, there is a nut connecting it to the rack.

For the pressure: I can easily loosen the nut with a wrench on the pump-connected side. For the other side, there is a nut connecting it to the rack.

However, the nut is inside and flush with the rack. So no wrench can be used here?

Comment: You'll need [something like this](http://www.etoolpros.com/Merchant5/graphics/00000001/asm-h4550.gif) to get at it ... I've seen what you're talking about, though have never had need to remove one.

Comment: @Paulster2  Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a wrench which looks something like this:

[image]

It's a type of crowsfoot wrench.